# What happens when we exceed the range value of Int8_t

Tags: c

I hope you can help me with this
What final value will x have ?

```
int32_t x = 0xE5;
int8_t i;

for(i=0;i<200;i++)
{
x++;
}`
```

What happens to int8_t when it exceeds its range of -128 to 127?

Thank you

Comment: You should be able to figure it out by yourself very easily. Have you tried to run your code? Have you started a debug session to see what happens? Open a memory monitor (add that variable to the watch list during a debug session) and see what happens when your variable goes outside the expected range.

Comment: Nobody knows what happens, because it's undefined.  You can try it and see, but please don't imagine that what you see is "the" answer, because it might do something different tomorrow, or under a different compiler.  It's like asking, "What happens when I drop a glass on the floor?"  It might break, or it might not.  (And if it does break, you might cut yourself badly, or not.)  If you want predictable behavior, don't drop glasses, and don't write code that overflows signed integer variables.

Comment: *What happens to int8_t when it exceeds its range of -128 to 127?*  It **can't**.  The posted code results in signed integer overflow and undefined behavior.

Comment: The speed limit on this road is 30 miles per hour, and the fastest my car can go is 100 miles per hour.  What will happen if I drive at 200 miles per hour?

Comment: @Alexis There is no way to reliably "figure it out".  Whatever happens can and likely will change depending on the compiler used, the exact options used to compile, the phase of the moon, and the migration of African swallows...

Comment: @Alexis *You should be able to figure it out by yourself...* Well, the OP can discover what happens under one compiler, on one computer, today.  But there's no guarantee that's what would happen under any other circumstances.

Comment: @SteveSummit Oh yeah.  :-)

Comment: @Alexis: It is bad advice to say people can “figure it out” by experimentation. In many circumstances, the C standard allows multiple results, sometimes even infinitely many results, and an experiment can only show one outcome in the particular circumstance it is tried it. It cannot provide a definitive answer on what the C standard specifies the behavior must be.

Comment: @SteveSummit: I do not believe the behavior in `for(i=0;i<200;i++)` itself is undefined. The C standard is vague about the semantics of `i++`, but, if it the increment portion is equivalent to `i += 1`, then the arithmetic is done in the `int` type, so there is no overflow in adding 127 to 1. Then the result, 128, is converted to `int8_t`, and that is implementation-defined, not undefined.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: See above comment.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Interesting observation.  But given the predilections of GCC's devs, odds are they'll interpret "the value of the operand object is incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it)" as invoking UB on overflow of a signed object's actual type, especially if C++ defines the postfix ++ operator in a way that makes overflow of signed types smaller than `int` undefined.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Re “*What happens to int8_t when it exceeds its range of -128 to 127?* It **can't**. The posted code results in signed integer overflow and undefined behavior”: It **can**. If the behavior is undefined, an `int8_t` object can have values outside −128 to +127.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'd think it would be more precise to say that, when undefined behavior is invoked, the behavior of a program could be unconstrained by what would otherwise be the expected limits.  Because there's no way you'll ever be able to cram `12317897` into an actual `uint8_t` object and then be able to pull that same value out again.  If you can, I recommend you patent the technique.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider what happens in `i++` when `i` is 127. The C standard’s specification of postfix `++` says, in C 2018 6.5.2.4 2:

> … As a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it)…

Unfortunately, it says nothing else about the arithmetic used; it does not say whether the addition is perform using `int8_t` arithmetic or `int` arithmetic or something else. In most operations in C, operands are promoted to at least the `int` type. For example, `i += 1` is specified to be effectively equivalent to `i = i + 1`, and `i + 1` is specified to promote this `i` to `int`. Then the addition yields 128, because 127 + 1 = 128 and 128 is representable in the `int` type. Then the 128 is converted to `int8_t` for storage in `i`. This is a problem because 128 is not representable in `int8_t`. C 2018 6.3.1.3 3 says there is either an implementation-defined result or an implementation-defined signal.

This means your compiler must document what happens here. There should be a manual for the compiler, and it should say what happens when an out-of-range result is converted to `int8_t`. For example, [GCC documents that the result wraps modulo 256](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation).

Since the standard is vague about the arithmetic used, it is possible the intent is the arithmetic would be performed in the `int8_t` type, and the addition would overflow, which has undefined behavior. But this would contrast with the general nature of the standard.

If the loop does continue, then `x++` will eventually exceed the `int32_t` type. If that is the same as the `int` type, it will overflow and have undefined behavior. If `int` is wider than `int32_t`, we have the same situation with a successful addition followed by an implementation-defined conversion.

Comment: *Since the standard is vague about the arithmetic used, it is possible the intent is the arithmetic would be performed in the `int8_t` type, and the addition would overflow, which has undefined behavior.* I would not be surprised if that were the most common interpretation of compiler developers - it would allow putting the `int8_t` into a larger register and use the assumption it could never exceed `INT8_MAX` to never check, for example letting it roll all the way up to `INT64_MAX` in a 64-bit register. Especially in optimized compilations. ISTR questions here where exactly that happened.